# How do I use pm2.start()?

Tags: javascript, pm2

It's my first time with pm2. I am particularly trying to use the programmatic API. Now when I call pm2.start('./app.js'), it doesn't look like the script is executed. In the sample code below, I expect to see "Working" in the console.

app.js

```
console.log('Working');
```

index.js

```
pm2.connect((err) => {
    pm2.start('./app.js', (err, d) => {
    });
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct only. PM2 write logs in **file instead of console**. So You can find logs in app-error.log file or app-out.log file.

```
var pm2 = require('pm2')

pm2.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log('ERROR ',err)
    }
    pm2.start('./app.js', (err, d) => {
        console.log('APP STARTED', err, d)
    });
});
```

You can find the log file path in the console.log('APP STARTED', err, d) output.

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Found the logs... Will take it up from there.

Comment: So I still run into issues. I keep getting the following error in the err_log file: `Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader`. Meanwhile the script I am trying to start only contains the `console.log('Working')` code.